# Fetch on external resource failing in RN Android emulators

Tags: android, react-native

Tried with both Genymotion 2 emulator with a `Custom Phone - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 768x1280 - 7.0` as well as a real device plugged in via USB `MotoG3 - 6.0.1`.

In both the cases fetch on a working JSON API externally hosted failed.

```
"TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12473:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:13376:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:15481:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:15337:14)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:15432:45
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3958:35)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2090:42)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:1948:15
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2062:9)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:1947:12)"
```

The same works on an ios simulator.

The issues reported below didn't help
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15100

My question is (I know java but not enough Android) - Where do I look for any logs / exceptions to understand the real reason it's failed. Because the API itself is functional and is working with an IOS simulator.

Comment: And the same error on a real device as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by fixing my ssl certificate.

https://in.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/SSL-Certificate-Issue-Android/td-p/49469

I had to write an Android HelloWorld App to get to a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems